# how to pass attributes of an object as arguments to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to send an object to a function, where the attributes are equal to the expected parameters.

Here is a code example:

```js
function fun(a, b, c){
    console.log('a='+a, 'b='+b, 'c='+c);
}

obj = {a:'1', b:'2', c:'3'};

fun(obj); //a=1 b=2 c=3
```

In python I would do = `fun(obj**)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ES6 you could simply do:

```
function fun(payload) {
   const {a = 'backup', b, c} = payload // assign a default argument for a if it is not available in the argument.
   console.log('a='+a, 'b='+b, 'c='+c)
}

obj = {a:'1', b:'2', c:'3'}

fun(obj) //a=1 b=2 c=3
```

This takes advantage of object restructuring, which makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables. In this case, it unpacks your variables `a, b, c` to be used inside the function.

Read more about this on MDN here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: does it work if some of the arguments don't exist in the object? (if I send an object that doesn't have an 'a' argument, for example)

Comment: Yes, you can add default arguments when you unpack your variable. I can update the example to show how to do that @CristianoFelipe

Comment: @CristianoFelipe if this answer helped you solve your issue - could you mark it as accepted? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use object destructuring

```js
function fun({a, b, c}) {
  console.log("a=" + a, "b=" + b, "c=" + c);
}

obj = { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3" };

fun(obj); //a=1 b=2 c=3
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it.

1 Using the dot operator as braces make the object an object literal.

```
function fun(obj){
    console.log('a='+obj.a, 'b='+obj.b, 'c='+obj.c);
}
obj = {a:'1', b:'2', c:'3'};
fun(obj); //a=1 b=2 c=3
```

2 Using ES6 destructuring (using this way you can easily assign default values in case object doesn't have those fields like -1 here)

```
function fun(obj){
    const {a = -1, b=-1, c=-1} = obj;
    console.log('a='+a, 'b='+b, 'c='+c);
}
obj = {a:'1', b:'2', c:'3'};
fun(obj); //a=1 b=2 c=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Object Destructing to do this

```
function fun(obj) {
 const {a, b, c} = obj;
 console.log("a=" + a, "b=" + b, "c=" + c);
}
obj = { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3" };
fun(obj);
```